# CEF Sharp Error On Latest Version

Tags: cefsharp

We are using the latest version of CEF Sharp (63.0.3) in a WPF application.
It works most of the time but at random we get the following error.

Faulting application name: Control.exe, version: 2018.4.18108.2, time stamp: 0x5ad7717f
Faulting module name: libcef.dll, version: 3.3239.1723.0, time stamp: 0x5a5407a4
Exception code: 0x80000003
Fault offset: 0x0000000002b1e729
Faulting process id: 0x1b24
Faulting application start time: 0x01d3d73fada69f89
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\USS G5\Control.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\USS G5\libcef.dll
Report Id: 21c697e3-433c-11e8-8115-00155d00652e
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Our application is compiled as 64 bit and it is running on Windows Server 2012 R2 with an Intel Xeon processor.
It looks like this issue was supposed to have been addressed in a prior version.

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1819
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1832

Does anyone know if this issue has been re-introduced or how to work around it?

Comment: I've not seen any other reports. You can test with cefclient, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#cefsharp-vs-chromium-embedded-frameworkcef

Comment: Also test with a Chromium 65 based build to see if the issue has been resolved.

Comment: I tried using the cef client and it won't even bring up the web page that we're trying to display.  The embedded browser in the application does display the web page correctly for the same URL.  In the cef client log file, it does display some warnings but no real errors.

Comment: 0419/140128.068:INFO:CONSOLE(638)] "bootstrap() has been depricated and will be removed the next major release. Use loadScript() instead.", source: https://mapit.utilitydistrict.com/vendor.bundle.js (638)
[0419/140128.077:INFO:CONSOLE(76059)] "Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.", source: https://mapit.utilitydistrict.com/vendor.bundle.js (76059)
[0419/140128.099:INFO:CONSOLE(73844)] "ERROR", source: https://mapit.utilitydistrict.com/vendor.bundle.js (73844)

Comment: Note that we are embedding a browser to display ESRI maps from our own server and this error only happens in release, we can not reproduce it in development.

Comment: Anyone has any update here? I'm having the exact same issue

Comment: We switched to the paid DotNetBrowser control to solve the issue.
This control is still built on Chromium, but doesn't have this issue that CEF sharp does.